Android Focus with Text Entry and Scrolling
Why doesn’t my UI automatically focus on where the user is entering data and how can I ensure it is?
When clicking a new edit area, it will make sure it is clearly on the screen, but entering text does not cause it to check that it hasn't scrolled out.
I believe I must be missing some fundamental UI understanding as I’m struggling with what I think should be an extremely basic UI pattern.
There are two main problems.

How do we ensure an area the user is entering text into is on screen? This only really applies to layouts that allow you to scroll outside. This is an extremely common pattern so I imagine this is a basic standard feature.
(Optional) If it is automatically ensuring the area is on screen, is it possible to add some padding to the bottom of that area so the text entry cursor is not resting directly on top of the soft keyboard. I want the user to see a row at the bottom of the card when they are typing near the bottom of the text entry area (but it may go out of view if they are typing at the top).

Here’s a minimal example (in an object so it can be easily copied / modified etc.):
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.imePadding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedCard
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

object StackAndroidTextEntryFocusWithLists {
    @Composable
    fun StackAndroidTextEntryFocusWithListsDisplay() {
        MainScaffold() {
            EditContent()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun MainScaffold(content : @Composable () -> Unit) {
        Scaffold {
            Box( Modifier.padding(it) ) {
                content()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun EditContent() {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Magenta) // highlights bounds
        ) {
            TenEditItems()
        }
    }
    // Code above should be safe (although I may be missing something obvious)

    // Code below here would likely need changing to get this to work as intended
    @Composable
    private fun TenEditItems() {
        val intList = (0 .. 10).toList()
        AsLazyColumnWithBottomItem(intList)
    }

    // This may need changing
    @Composable
    private fun AsLazyColumnWithBottomItem(intList: List<Int>) {
        LazyColumn {
            items(intList) {
                EditItemCard()
                Spacer(Modifier.padding(8.dp))
            }
            item {
                Spacer(
// Spacing at bottom of list allows user to scroll below text entry if on last item
// NOTE: This behaves strangely as clicking on the text entry area again can reduce the spacing
                    Modifier
                        .imePadding()
                )
            }
        }
    }

    // This may need changing
    @Composable
    private fun EditItemCard() {
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("")}
        OutlinedCard {
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
            ) {
                Text("If the user enters any data, the data entry carat must be on screen\n" +
                        "The list needs to jump if not focused on the right card")
                TextField(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    value = text,
                    onValueChange = { text = it }
                )
                // Currently, these lines below are not visible. The keyboard appears just above them
                // on the last item in the list
                Text("These lines MUST always be visible when editing this card\n" +
                        "Test by scrolling to last card in the list")
            }
        }
    }
}

After searching and also trying AI (GPT and Claude), I was unable to find any working solutions for this. As this is such a common pattern, I believe there must be a fundamental basic problem with my UI.
What I've tried:

List item Manually using scrollState to scroll to the card being edited - this works a little, but it doesn't know where the cursor is so it might jump to the bottom or top of the card and still not show the text being edited
List item Restricting the size of the text box (I don't want to do this as I want to let it dynamically grow as usual, even it it gets bigger than the screen
List item Using imePadding in various locations

I didn't work too much on manual solutions for this as I am sure this must be a basic feature. I don't want to create a custom solution for something that is already built in.
Of interest #1 - (but not part of the question):
In addition, there is another area of concern caused by my imePadding Spacer. It seems to have some strange behavior near the end of the list. The first time you select the edit text area (and scroll down as far as it allows), the extra padding area is quite big; however, selecting the edit text box a second time, the space reduces to about a quarter of what it was. Here are the ImeTracker logs:
Initial click onto text edit area:
 ImeTracker : onRequestShow at ORIGIN_CLIENT reason SHOW_SOFT_INPUT_BY_INSETS_API fromUser false
 ImeTracker : onRequestShow at ORIGIN_CLIENT reason SHOW_SOFT_INPUT fromUser false
 ImeTracker : onShown

Second click:
ImeTracker : onRequestShow at ORIGIN_CLIENT reason SHOW_SOFT_INPUT_BY_INSETS_API fromUser false
ImeTracker : onCancelled at PHASE_CLIENT_APPLY_ANIMATION
ImeTracker : onRequestShow at ORIGIN_CLIENT reason SHOW_SOFT_INPUT fromUser false
ImeTracker : onCancelled at PHASE_CLIENT_APPLY_ANIMATION

Of interest #2 - (but not part of the question):
When posting this question on the StackOverflow website, my question was long enough so the text entry area was no longer on screen when scrolled down (text entry above). If I scrolled to the bottom then entered a character on my keyboard with the text entry area selected, it attempted to jump up to show me where I was typing but failed and show the top of the question.
